# How to prove that the L2 norm is a non-increasing function of time for a 2nd-order PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, partial-derivative, heat-equation

I am having a test in few days and I saw an interesting question while I was skimming through the book problems.

The problem is concerned about initial-boundary value problem of 2nd order PDEs. To be specific, a IBVP problem of the diffusion (heat) equation.

---

Let us say I have the diffusion equation in 1-D, with the diffusivity constant to be unity (for simplicity):

[image]

with the following conditions imposed on the PDE:

[image]

**Now, I want to prove that the [image] norm of [image] is a non-increasing function of time (assuming the norm of [image] to be finite.)**

- Well I know that this norm is defined as [image][image]
- How can I start the proof? Shall I use the Poincare inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^L u^2(t,x) dx = \int_0^L 2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} u dx = \int_0^L 2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} u dx$$

Now integrate by parts. Your boundary term will vanish, and the remaining integral term will be the integral of a nonpositive function, so it will be nonpositive. So all that's left is to justify the differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: $\\2\int_{0}^{L}\frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial x^2}s dx
\\
\\
\\u=s, dv=\frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial x^2}dx
\\du=ds,v=\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}

\\
\\
\\\therefore 2\int_{0}^{L}\frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial x^2}s dx=2s\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}\mid-\int_{0}^{L}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}ds=-\int_{0}^{L}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}ds$           Thanks! But is that sufficient?

Comment: You made an error: with $u=s$ you get $du=\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} dx$. This gives another factor of $\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry I didn't get it. How come $du=\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}dx$? We have two symbols (u & s) on the right-hand side.

Comment: Er, typo, $du=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} dx$. In other words you get $\int_0^L \frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial x^2} s dx = s \frac{\partial s}{\partial x} |_0^L - \int_0^L \left ( \frac{\partial s}{\partial x} \right )^2 dx$. What you wrote was correct, but you still needed to write $ds = \frac{\partial s}{\partial x} dx$ in order to finish the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I hope that is correct now:                   $\\2\int_{0}^{L}\frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial x^2}s dx
\\
\\
\\u=s, dv=\frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial x^2}dx
\\du=\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}dx,v=\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}

\\
\\
\\\therefore 2\int_{0}^{L}\frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial x^2}s dx=2s\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}\mid-2\int_{0}^{L}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}dx=-2\int_{0}^{L}(\frac{\partial s}{\partial x})^{2}dx$

Comment: Yes, now the integrand is a square, so with the minus sign you get what you want.